# Excel VBA. Creating Pivot Table from Personal.xlsb

Tags: vba, excel, pivot, pivot-table

Code works perfectly fine, when module is imported directly to the workbook. 
Trying to launch VBA code from Personal.xlsb - gives an error.

> Run-time error '5'
>   Invalid procedure call or argument.)

`Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Count` gives zero, meaning there is no data in the cache.

Need help in defining data source from `personal.xlsb`

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

Set pc = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
SourceData:=Sheet1.Name & "!" & Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address, _
Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Count

Worksheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Range("A3").Select

Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable( _
    TableDestination:=ActiveCell, _
    TableName:="ReportPivot")'
```

Comment: is Personal.xlsb  the name of a workbook that you want to run the code above in? And on which line does the error occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Thisworkbook` always references the workbook holding the code - in this case your Personal workbook.  Instead you probably want to reference the `Activeworkbook`.

In the code below I've set a reference to the ActiveWorkbook just after variable declaration. The PivotCache, PivotTable and any formula all reference the ActiveWorkbook.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wrkBk As Workbook
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim wrkSht2 As Worksheet
    Dim pc As PivotCache
    Dim pt As PivotTable

    Set wrkBk = ActiveWorkbook

    Set wrkSht = wrkBk.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Set pc = wrkBk.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=wrkSht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address, _
    Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

    Debug.Print wrkBk.PivotCaches.Count

    Set wrkSht2 = wrkBk.Worksheets.Add
    wrkSht2.Name = "PivotTable"

    Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable( _
        TableDestination:=wrkSht2.Range("A3"), _
        TableName:="ReportPivot")

End Sub
```

Comment: That was what I was thinking!

Comment: Didn't think he'd want it in the Personal workbook as that's usually hidden.  Handy place to keep code and lookup lists for personal use only though.

Comment: I don't know why I haven't yet explored doing that. I am still with the dinosaurs and "GoTo"

Comment: Think the last time I used "GoTo" was Sinclair Basic back in the 80's :D

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. This code worked out. 
- I replaced ThisWorkbook with ActiveWorkbook
- I replaced Sheet1.Name with ActiveSheet.Name
- I replaced Sheet1.Range with ActiveSheet.Range

'
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

```
Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
SourceData:=ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & 
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address, _
Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Count

Worksheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Range("A3").Select

Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable( _
    TableDestination:=ActiveCell, _
    TableName:="ReportPivot")'
```